# CSS background-color won't work?

Tags: html, css

So, I am REALLY noob in CSS, as in I have only used it only 1 or 2 times. When I try to change the body's background color it doesn't change at all.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" src = "CSS/main.css">
    <title>
        TESTTITLE
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color : aliceblue;
}
```

I know this is pretty simple, but I am really a beginner in the whole front end thing.

Comment: Probably an incorrectly linked stylesheet.  Inline it works: http://jsbin.com/kenehuyoqa/edit?html,output.  Do you get any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Mistake linking the CSS file `src = "CSS/main.css"` must be `href="CSS/main.css"`

Comment: Your doctype syntax is wrong also, it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mis-used `src`.

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

Comment: well that was a dumb thing to do :p ty very much

Comment: No problem! Remember if the question was helpful to accept it with the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.body {
     background-color: aliceblue;
}
</style>
```

This is one way to fix your problem if you include a style tag such as this one just before your head tag.